# Effective way to unset session array in php/symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

php unset is working but on reload the session data is still there:
I'm building simple addtocart and remove from cart in php/symfony5, but I'm unable to unset the array from multi dimension array in symfony session.

```
^ array:3 [▼
0 => array:1 [▼
  "items" => array:4 [▼
    0 => 9
    1 => "Dry fruit"
    2 => "1234"
    3 => "250g"
  ]
]
1 => array:1 [▼
   "items" => array:4 [▼
   0 => 8
   1 => "Pumpkin"
   2 => "123"
   3 => "x"
 ]
```

]

This is my cart controller:

```
        $basket = $session->get('basket',[]);
    dump($basket);
    $size = $session->get('size');
    if($request->isMethod('POST')){
       $id = $request->request->get('0');
       foreach($basket as $key => $value){
           if($value['items'][0] == $id){
            unset($basket[$key]['items']);
            dd($basket);
            //$session->set('basket',[]);
            //return $this->redirectToRoute('cart');
           }
       }

    }
```

On the above code when I click remove button in twig and when dd($basket) is done the array is empty like below:

```
^ array:3 [▼
0 => [] //empty
1 => array:1 [▼
"items" => array:4 [▼
  0 => 8
  1 => "Pumpkin"
  2 => "123"
  3 => "x"
]
```

]

But, when I comment dd($basket) and page is reloaded the array is as it is like before(seems reverted idk) and if I uncomment $session->set('basket',[]); everything is empty.

what I want to achieve here is, how to remove array from session multi dimension array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to set the session variable to the updated `$basket` value.

```
// get a copy of the basket from the session
$basket = $session->get('basket',[]);

// do whatever to update $basket here

// overwrite the basket in the session
$session->set('basket', $basket);

// then return a Response
```

Comment: Thank you, Arleigh it worked with small modification. In above array , 0 => [], will throw an error(which I didn't notice) because if there is  some sort of array operation it expects the array element(s). Inorder to avoid that we must also  pop out 0 => [] from the session array. So what I did was I used : unset($basket[$key]); anyway thank you your answer worked at the end. Please update your answer how  0 => [] may cause an error.